How to fit and perform diagnostics for (Linear) Mixed Effects Models on Rating data in R
I conducted an experiment where 143 test subjects (Interview) rated sets of 20 Stimuli (Stimulus) on a scale from 0 to 100. Stimuli were drawn at random for each participant from a pool of 80, with two categories (Axis and Allied, 10 drawn per category). The set of stimuli were first presented and rated under the short exposure (Gist) condition, with a second set of ratings obtained under the long exposure (LE) condition afterwards. To sum up, we have different subjects rating different sets of stimuli and two ratings per stimulus per subject.
Ratings for the two viewing conditions were recorded in two separate columns, RatingGist and RatingLE, respectively with a third column RatingDELTA, with a scale from -100 to +100 added for the difference between a subjects' LE and Gist ratings for the same Stimulus.
In addition to the ratings, my dataset contains additional variables recorded at the participant-level (Sex, PolNum) and at the Stimulus-level (Semiotics), where PolNum is a participant's political orientation recorded on a continuous Left-Right scale (-3 to +3) and Semiotics (dummy-coded) indicates whether political symbols are visible in a given Stimulus.
My aim is to investigate whether political orientation and stimulus category and image content can be used to predict ratings under long exposure  and/or change in ratings between viewing conditions (RatingDELTA).
My idea was to fit three separate models:

RatingLE as the dependent variable, RatingGist as baseline

RatingDELTA as the dependent variable, with RatingGist as a baseline

RatingGist as the dependent variable, the hypothesis being that under short exposure, political information is not extracted from stimuli and cognitive processes that might alter the perception of the image based on semantic content don't kick in.


Now, in terms of fitting the LMM, I started off by defining my random effects structure and fitting a null-model without fixed effects predictors:
delta_0 <- lmer(RatingDELTA ~ 1 + (1 | Interview) + (1 | Stimulus)

LE_0 <- lmer(RatingLE ~ 1 + (1 | Interview) + (1 | Stimulus)

Gist_0 <- lmer(RatingGist ~ 1 + (1 | Interview) + (1 | Stimulus)

I then proceeded to add my fixed effects in a stepwise fashion, one predictor at a time, comparing fit indices (AIC, log likelihood and pseudo-$R^2$) between iterations until I arrived at what is now my full model:
delta_6 <- lmer(RatingDELTA ~ RatingGist + PolNum*Publisher + Sex + Semiotics*PolNum + (1  + RatingGist + Publisher | Interview) + (1 | Stimulus), data = dfx, REML = FALSE)

LE_6 <- lmer(RatingLE ~ RatingGist + PolNum*Publisher + Sex + Semiotics*PolNum + (1  + RatingGist + Publisher | Interview) + (1 | Stimulus), data = dfx, REML = FALSE)

(I've omitted the Gist model here since none of the previously used predictors improved the model – they did, however, for a GLMM with a transformed DV (rescaled to 0.0001–0.9999) with a beta-link function).
Each predictor and inclusion of the interaction terms significantly improved fit for the LE and Delta models, but I am having trouble determining whether or not the models were specified correctly in the first place. I have been using DHARMa for diagnostics but I simply do not have the statistical know-how nor the experience to adequately assess them (residual diagnostic plots for the delta_6 model are shown below).

For one, I am unsure whether LMMs can be fit directly to the ratings themselves, as their scales are double-bounded and there does appear to be a slight pattern in the residual plot (shown below).

I have played around with beta mixed regression and zero-inflated beta mixed regression models for the Gist and LE-models using glmmTMB, but I don't know how to correctly set up DHARMa to run the diagnostics and what to look for.
If anyone could recommend a comprehensive diagnostic strategy for my LMMs and how to decide between LMM or GLMM with a specific link function for the Gist and LE models, I would greatly appreciate it. If needed, I can also provide the original data, though at over 2000 observations, it is somewhat large.
EDIT I've added histograms showing the distributions of my DVs below:

RatingDELTA = RatingLE – RatingGist



I'm confused by your dependent variables. Are the dependent variables simply measuring the same thing under different conditions? If so, I'm not sure the multiple models are necessary. It would also be helpful to know exactly what each DV measures.

Yes, RatingGist and RatingLE measure the same thing, which is liking/aesthetic pleasure. So if we were to consider every combination of subject and Stimulus in the data as an observation, we have repeated observations. We also have repeated measures per subject, as each subject rates multiple Stimuli that were drawn at random from a larger pool, so our Stimuli did not receive ratings from all subjects but from a random subset of them, with the n=ratings per Stimulus ranging from 20 to 100, hence the Mixed model approach.

I think including condition as a fixed effect rather than having three different DVs (and consequently three potential models) is a much better alternative if the DV is measuring the same thing each time. What was the reason for differentiating them in the first place? And why is the DV double-bounded? Is it a count that has a theoretical maximum? How often do people hit the ceiling/floor values?

I see your point regarding separate models vs one unified model. The reasoning behind me fitting multiple models here was that I am mainly interested in examining the influence of my fixed effect predictors separately for each experimental condition since my hypothesis is that these predictors have a significant effect on ratings obtained under the LE condition, but not under Gist.
As for the scaling of the DVs, both RatingGist and RatingLE have upper and lower limits. I have added histograms showing their distributions, which look zero- or zero-one-inflated to me.

Since these seem to be proportions, I think this would be better modeled as a beta GLMM using the condition as a factor rather than a DV. The rating LE and GIST seem to both show that the boundedness is restricting the range of values and likely contributing to a degree to poor predictions from the standardized residuals, so a beta distribution would likely be better (where you would need to transform the data accordingly). You may need to add a very small constant to zeroes and ones to allow it to fit. I'd recommend another answerer chimes in about that, as I may be wrong.

I agree with @ShawnHemelstrand that it's better to have one model for all the data. You can explore this: "my hypothesis is that these predictors have a significant effect on ratings obtained under the LE condition, but not under Gist" by including an interaction in the model. I'm not sure that the Y values are proportions though, even if they are in the [0,100] range. I interpret "rating" to be an ordinal variable (with 0 to 100 stars instead of the usual 5; the floor and ceiling effects suggest that participants struggled with that.) So you can also try ordinal regression.

Happened to remember a blog post that, I think, discusses a related situation: How to analyze visual analog (slider) scale data?. Suggests a quite different approach too.
